# How can I sort values for stacked plot graph in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, plot

I have a problem about sorting values by the number of PrimaryRole.

I wrote some codes to draw a stacked plot graph but each bar is sorted by PrimaryRole like A-Z. What I want to do is to learn how I can sort it with respect to the total number of PrimaryRole.

Here is my code snippet which is shown below.

```
df = df.groupby(['Manufacturer','PrimaryRole']).size() \
                             .reset_index() \
                             .pivot(columns='Manufacturer', index='PrimaryRole', values=0)


ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,figsize=(20,10), colormap='rainbow')
plt.title('Title', fontsize=20) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer which is shown below.

After summing all rows into **"Sum"** column , the **sorting** process is implemented. That's why I can solve the issue.

```
df["Sum"] = df.sum(axis=1)

ax = df.sort_values('Sum', ascending=False).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,figsize=(20,10), colormap='rainbow')
```